# RxJava filter list inside observable

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I have object

### Response

```
public class Response {
    private List<Content> content;

    public static class Content {
        private boolean rated;
    }
}
```

and I would like to filter `List<Content> content` by `rated` value. Im trying to do this like this

```
mResponseProvider.reponse()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMapIterable(response -> response.getContent())
                .filter(content -> mAAA.isRated(content.getRated()))
                .toList()
                .subscribe(response -> {
                    doSomethingWithResponse(response);
                });
```

But the problem is that my `response` in `.subscribe()` is `List<Content>`. How can I get in `.subscribe()` `Response` object with filtered values for `List<Content>` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
mResponseProvider.reponse()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .filter(response -> mAAA.isRated(response.getContent())) //1
            .subscribe(response -> {
                doSomethingWithResponse(response);
            });
```

//1  try to change argument to List in isRated

Comment: Content object contains more properties but I would like to filter this list only by rated property